# SQL extract substring from text column

Tags: sql, sqlite, substring

I have the following table and I want to extract the year from the second column (as show in the second table).

```
Points | Year
______________
100    | 04/07/2014 - 06/07/2014
200    | 22/06/2017 - 24/06/2017
300    | 30/06/2015 - 02/07/2015

Points | Year
______________
100    | 2014
200    | 2017
300    | 2015
```

My approach is using the substring statement but doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT Points, SUBSTRING(Year, 5, 4) as Year
FROM tabel1;
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Your index starts from 7 for year

Comment: your second column looks like interval, than date, so if interval have different years, which one you want to extract ?

Comment: And which year you wanted to extract ? Interval starting year or end year?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am reading from a csv and then extracting again into a csv after executing this query that's why I am storing as a varchar.

Comment: The interval is only 3 days and never includes a year change that's why either the first or the second is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use SUBSTR() instead of SUBSTRING()

Answer (score 0):

If your using mysql why arent you using extract which is more precise than substring?!

SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "2017-06-15")